# Rounding a variable to the nearest integer

Tags: javascript, variables, rounding

I have some code that rounds a variable to the nearest integer - except I cant seem to get it to round a variable to the nearest integer. Here's my code:

```
var score = 600;
var coinBase = 400;
var coinInt = score / coinBase;
var coin = round(VARIABLEcoinInt');
```

In other words, I'm trying to get the variable coinInt, round it to the nearest whole number, and outputting it in the variable coin.

Comment: in the old days, you had to add a half and take an integer of it.

Comment: Use `Math.round()` function

Comment: Firstly, `round` is not a valid `Javascript` method. Secondly `round(VARIABLEcoinInt')` is invalid syntax. Thirdly `VARIABLEcoinInt` isnt a defined variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `round` function. Use `Math.round` function instead.

```js
var score = 600;
var coinBase = 400;
var coinInt = score / coinBase;
var coin = Math.round(coinInt);

console.log(coin);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the 3 `Math` based functions.

`Math.round` - Rounds to the nearest whole integer:

```
Math.round(1.4) // 1
Math.round(1.5) // 2
```

`Math.floor` - Rounds down

```
Math.floor(1.2) // 1
Math.floor(1.9) // 1
```

`Math.ceil` - Rounds up

```
Math.ceil(1.2) // 2
Math.ceil(1.9) // 2
```